# How do I embed the home page of an Enterprise Wiki as a webpart?

Tags: 2010, web-part, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

I'd like to embed the home page of our wiki into another page. I'd rather not use the `?IsDlg=1` trick as that still includes the title bar.

Comment: If I understand well you don't want to use the page viewer web part because you don't want the title to be displayed?

Comment: There are still some page options at the top, and as it's an iframe, clicking on a wiki link opens up the pages inside the iframe, rather than as a new window. It feels like a hack, surely there is a better way to embed one sharepoint page in another?

Comment: It is in the "nature" of iframes to keep all in the frame, and of course even link are opened there. 
There are workarounds to try to solve (e g [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022741/how-to-make-links-inside-an-iframe-to-open-outside-this-iframe]), but I think you should instead structure differently. I would try to play with _open as a dialog_ option.

Comment: Thats why I don't want to use the page viewer web part. Can you expand your "Open as a dialog" comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is in the "nature" of iframes to keep all in the frame, and of course even link are opened there. There are workarounds to try to solve (e g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022741/how-to-make-links-inside-an-iframe-to-open-outside-this-iframe)), but I think you should instead structure differently. I would try to play with open as a dialog option.